# Recursive or complex templating with Angular 1.x

Tags: angularjs, recursion, angular-template

I have a data structure (sample provided below) where I need to iterate upon this set of questions and be able to template them in angular. Each "question" has this structure:

```
{
    id: 2, // unique id
    label: 'some label', // any label
    type: 'input', // the type of html element
    options: [], // other questions are nested in here (recursive)
    children: [] // other questions are nested in here (recursive)
}
```

As mentioned above, the type describes the type of html element and the difference between `options` and `children` is that the set of `questions` that rendered in `options` are display in the same line as the parent question whereas the `questions` inside of `children` are rendered one line below with a little bit of left margin.

I'm not familiar enough with Angular on how you'd achieve this, given that the basic `ng-repeat` would no suffice here (from what I understand) and I'm curious how one would go about templating this sort of data structure.

Many thanks, in advance, for the help!

Here's a sample data structure:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        label: 'something',
        type: 'text',
        options: [
            {
                id: 2,
                label: 'another',
                type: 'text',
                options: [],
                children: []
            }
        ],
        children: [
            {
                id: 83,
                label: 'cool',
                type: 'input',
                options: [],
                children: []
            },
            {
                id: 121,
                label: 'another cool thing',
                type: 'label',
                options: [
                    {
                        id: 451,
                        label: 'only a label',
                        type: '',
                        options: [],
                        children: [
                            {
                                id: 901,
                                label: 'a cool info',
                                type: 'label',
                                options: [],
                                children: []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                children: []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 27,
        label: 'some text',
        type: 'label',
        options: [
            {
                id: 541,
                label: 'hey there',
                type: 'label',
                options: [],
                children: []
            }
        ],
        children: [
            {
                id: 761,
                label: 'hi there',
                type: 'checkbox',
                options: [],
                children: []
            },
            {
                id: 165,
                label: 'cool',
                type: 'text',
                options: [
                    {
                        id: 1090,
                        label: 'neat',
                        type: 'input',
                        options: [],
                        children: [
                            {
                                id: 9891,
                                label: 'tell me',
                                type: 'textarea',
                                options: [],
                                children: []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                children: []
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: You'd need to use nested ng-repeats and apply ng-class depending on the kind of item you are looping trough to make options and children look different applying css classes.

Comment: Yes, that's what I originally had, however, it doesn't solve the following issues:
---------
1) nested ng-repeats is only as good as many the levels you write. hence why I was wondering if there's any other way of doing this -------
2) ng-class doesn't account for the different types of html elements. i was thinking of using ng-switch and having all the various ones there, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using ng-if instead ng-class so you can call an external html template on the fly. You could event tune that template to have inside another ng-repeat if options or children exists so you loop till the end of the array/object no matter it's depth.

Comment: Do you have any examples by chance?